# Realizar la cantidad de INSERT'S según el número de registros devueltos por una consulta previa en MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, bucles, insert

Muy buenas a todos.

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, el cual expondré de forma muy detallada con un ejemplo muy básico:

La tabla TBL_EJEMPLO_1 consta de la siguiente estructura:

```
id registro estado fechaModificacion
1  abc      3      Hace 25Dias
2  def      2      Hace 40Dias
3  ghi      1      Hace 2Dias
4  jkl      3      Hace 100Dias
5  mnñ      2      Hace 57Dias
```

El campo "*estado*" de esa tabla tiene cierto significado a nivel empresarial. Cada día se van agregando nuevos registros a esa tabla, por lo cual, se entiende que es una tabla bastante grande.

Existe una segunda tabla, la cual llamaremos TBL_EJEMPLO_2, en donde se registra una serie de seguimientos que sólo se ponen cuando el estado de los registros de TBL_EJEMPLO_1 llega al valor 3. Ésta tiene una estructura básica como la siguiente:

```
id registro seguimiento
1  abc      Éste registro está en el nivel 3
2  jkl      Éste registro está en el nivel 3
```

Teniendo ya eso claro, se requiere un cambio de estado de carácter masivo, mediante un JOB (*o tarea/evento programada*) que se ejecute de forma diaria cuando los registros en TBL_EJEMPLO_1 tengan más de 1 mes en un estado distinto al 3 (*es decir, que lleven más de 1 mes sin haber alcanzado o cambiado al estado 3 por los demás procesos del sistema que lo harían de forma natural*).

En ese sentido, **lo que se debe hacer son 2 cosas sencillas**: **un update en TBL_EJEMPLO_1** para cambiar el estado a 3 de todos los registros que lleven más de 1 mes **y un insert en TBL_EJEMPLO_2**, para agregar el seguimiento de que, dicho registro ya alcanzó el nivel 3.

En tal JOB, hacer el update es bastante simple, puesto que, con un simple IN, se pueden pueden actualizar todos los registros que cumplan con esa condición, siendo algo así:

**update TBL_EJEMPLO_1 set estado = 3 where fechaModificacion <= curdate() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH and estado not in (3)**

Con ese update ya dentro del job, siempre que se ejecute modificará todos los registros que cumplan tales condiciones inmediatamente, los cuales, para el ejemplo, serán los id 2 y 5; el 3 no porque no cumple con lo del mes, dejando la tabla así:

```
id registro estado fechaModificacion
1  abc      3      Hace 25Dias
2  def      3      Hace 40Dias
3  ghi      1      Hace 2Dias
4  jkl      3      Hace 100Dias
5  mnñ      3      Hace 57Dias
```

El problema entonces radica a la hora de hacer el INSERT masivo en TBL_EJEMPLO_2; por ende, la preguntá entonces está en el **cómo puedo implementar una sentencia para capturar los diversos valores "*registro*" de TBL_EJEMPLO_1 e irlos insertando, posiblemente con un ciclo, dentro de TBL_EJEMPLO_2**.

En otras palabras, un INSERT masivo de el seguiente estilo:

**insert into TBL_EJEMPLO_2 (registro, seguimiento) values (x, 'Éste registro está en el nivel 3')**

Espero se haya entendido, y pues, gracias de antemano.

¡Saludos!

Comment: No termino de entender tu ejemplo, podras aclararlo un poco mas??? por lo que veo, necesitas un select into table???

Answer (score 0):

por lo que entendí quiere hacer un insert con los datos que cumplan la condicion de estado =3 y fechaModificacion <= a 3 meses, espero que te ayude en algo el siguiente script:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_EJEMPLO_2 (registro, seguimiento) 
SELECT 
    registro , 
    'Éste registro está en el nivel 3' 
FROM 
    TBL_EJEMPLO_1 
WHERE  
    estado = 3
        AND fechaModificacion <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH);
```